# To step up to a broken promise

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language

Could anyone help me understand the meaning of this apparently idiomatic expression:

> "To step up to a broken promise."

I did not find it on the net. I'll appreciate it.

Comment: I think I know what it might mean, but context would help. Where did you see/read/hear it? Is there a source you can link to?

Comment: The fact that you didn't find it in a general search is a good indicator that it's *not* an idiom.

Comment: I appreciate your help. A friend of mine asked me the question and I posted it here for you all to see. Unfortunately she's not able to give me information regarding the source and context  at the moment. She says she's left the book at work. I will try to get in touch with her on Saturday.

Comment: I'm sorry for choosing wrong tags for my question. English is not my native tongue and what I do not know far exceeds what I might know.
Thanks for your time and concern. God bless.

Comment: I finally obtained some information about the source. It is a book titled "Crucial Accountability" purchased from this site: 
https://www.vitalsmarts.com/crucial-accountability-training/
And the expression is used in the following paragraph:
For this assignment, we’ll ask you to actually step up to a broken promise or two and start the accountability discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different phrases here: "step up to" and "broken promise".

**Together, these two phrases are not idiomatic**.

## Step Up

To step up means:

> to take action when there is a need or opportunity for it:
>
> -- [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/step-up)

## Broken Promise

A **broken promise** is simply when you do ..

> ... **not do what you said that you would do.**
>
> -- [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/promise#cald4-1-2-1)

## This phrase

> "To step up to a broken promise."

This phrase is unclear, for several reasons.  It is basically a **mixed metaphor**:

You can step up to a challenge or an opportunity, but we don't use the phrase "broken promise" this way.

We use the phrase "broken promise" to describe **the problem**, not the opportunity that the problem **creates**.

You could say:

> - Alice broke her promise to help Bob.
> - Charlie saw what was happening, and `stepped up` to help.
>     or
> - .. **`stepped in`** <sup>([Definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/step-in#cald4-1-1-1))</sup> to help.

Or you could say:

> - Dr. Green broke his promise to work on saturday.
> - Dr. White stepped up {`and agreed to come in from her vacation`}.

Notice how the highlighted part explains how Dr. White stepped up.  Dr. White is not *stepping up to the broken promise*, she is stepping up to **help solve the problem left by [or created by] the broken promise**.

You can even **leave out** the entire highlighted part.  Once you **describe the problem**, it is okay to say "stepped up" afterwards:

> - Mary:  Dr. Green broke his promise to work on saturday.
> - Sue:   Yes, and Dr. White stepped up.

Once we know what Dr. Green did, it is clear what Dr. White did.

Changing "stepped up" to refer to the **opportunity instead of the problem** might seem like a small change in the meaning, but it is the right way to use the idiomatic (almost slang) phrase "step up".

Comment: 'We use the phrase "broken promise" to describe the problem, not the opportunity that the problem creates." This is very clarifying, thanks. Every bit of your answer is quite helpful. I appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you!  If this answer helped you please hit the green ✔️ to mark the question as “solved”!  Keep contributing and welcome to E. L. L./S. E.!